# Start activity with compose get TransactionTooLargeException error

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to start an intent to open external app , the process work fine if i call it inside MainActivity (xml or compose) But when call it from Compose Screen i get this error **java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 9240036 bytes**

code:

```
val receiptIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$phoneNumber&text=${encodedUrl}"))
activity.startActivity(receiptIntent) //activity : MainActivity
//context.startActivity(receiptIntent) //val context = LocalContext.current
```

I am trying to open external app to do specific process.

Comment: It looks like your URI is too large, you can fit around 1MB of data in the transaction (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html) and it says your data is closer to 9MB. Is `encodedUrl` a massive string?

Comment: when i replace encoded Url with any short string i get same error